# Units on the attribute table of GIS dataset - California Counties 2016

Tags: data.gov

I am using California county Data from 2016, from the US census site
Dataset: CA_Counties_TIGER2016

Metadata: https://catalog.data.gov/harvest/object/8933496c-7da8-486e-aa66-64981962a3c5/html

What are the units of column Aland?

When I run statistics using Arcmap they show a sum of 403501101370 (which does not seem to match  California;s landmass when calculated in sq m, km, acres)

[image: Census Table in a Spreadsheet Editor.]

Comment: Hi Welcome to Open Data SE. Please provide enough attribution to the question else it would be difficult to answer your question

Answer (score 1):

ALAND is supposed to be m^2. Example: Sierra County should be about 2.492 × 10^9 m^2. Which county or counties look off? AWATER has same units.